# Meaning of “The retail stores are a way to help people get exposed to the lifestyle,”

Tags: meaning, translation, russian

From http://fortune.com/2015/07/23/bulletproof-coffee-funding/

> Asprey sees the coffee shop locations as an important way to hook new customers on the high-calorie concoction. As he said, anybody can buy and brew coffee — any coffee — at home, but Asprey wants to offer a store experience to his customers.
>
> “**The retail stores are a way to help people get exposed to the lifestyle,**” Scholnick said. “I think that *bulletproof* has the potential to be a national and a global movement and brand.”

Please explain what the **bold** phrase in this text means. I think it's either

- The retail stores  can affect the lifestyle of people.

or

- The retail stores can demonstrate this lifestyle to people.

Comment: Welcome to ELU; I've (heavily) edited the question to include the relevant part of the article. Even though you provided the link, displaying some context is usually a good idea if you want helpful, relevant answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the article is trying to say is:

> The retail stores will familiarize people to the lifestyle (here, in
>   this context, the coffee that is different).

As Scholnick  himself says in the article, anyone can brew a coffee at home but a retail store experience would be unique. So his idea is to entice customers to visit the retail stores so that he can get them to buy and like the coffee.

Answer (score 0):

They want to make money by selling coffee with butter in it. The article is pretentious hype and you should not attach much meaning to such loosely constructed prose. "The" lifestyle is not defined, except by some vague allusion to "hacking", whatever that means. Don't waste your time on such empty nonsense.